# List iterator implementation in map implementation - trouble

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator, nodes

Iterator implementation in template class List of DataType's.

```
 template <DataType>
 class List{
        ...

    class myIterator
    {
    public:
        typedef myIterator self_type;
        typedef Node<DataType>* pointer;

        myIterator(pointer ptr) : ptr_(ptr) { }
        self_type operator++() {
            self_type i = *this;
            if (ptr_) ptr_ = ptr_->Next();
            return i;
        }
        int operator*() { if (ptr_ ) return ptr_->Data(); else return 0; }
        bool operator==(const self_type& rhs) {
            if (!ptr_ && !rhs.ptr_) return true;
            return (ptr_ && rhs.ptr_ && rhs.ptr_->Data()==ptr_->Data());
        }
        bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) {
            return !(*this==rhs);
        }
    private:
        pointer ptr_ = nullptr;
    };

    myIterator begin() { return myIterator(head); }
    myIterator end() { return myIterator(nullptr); }
};
```

Use:

```
void remove(const KeyType& key) {
            if (!this->containsKey(key)) {
                return;
            }
            for (List<Pair, CompareFunction>::myIterator it = this->_pairs.begin();
            it != this->_pairs.end(); ++it) {
                Pair cur_pair = *it;
                if (cur_pair.first == key) {
                    this->_pairs.Delete(cur_pair);
                    this->_size--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Relevant code of header of this func:

```
template <class KeyType, class ValueType, class CompareFunction = std::less<KeyType> >
    class MtmMap {

    public:
        class Pair {
        public:
            Pair() :first(KeyType()) {} ////////////////////
            Pair(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value)
                : first(key), second(value) {}

            const KeyType first;
            ValueType second;

            ~Pair() = default;

            Pair& operator=(const Pair& pair) {
                this->second = pair.second;
                return *this;
            }
        };
```

**Purpose:**
What I'm trying to do in that loop, is to iterate over the whole list and find the pair, in which the key is the same as given and then delete the whole pair.

**The problem:**

```
*it
```

is interpreted as int, which in our case I guess leaks from the MtmMap, because in my "main":

```
typedef MtmMap<int, int> IntMap;
typedef IntMap::Pair IntPair;

IntMap map1(10);
map1.insert(IntPair(1, 2));
map1.remove(1);
```

Error:

```
" cannot convert from "int" to "mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::Pair" ""
```

**Edit:**
I have another problem, which is in the next piece of code:

```
const ValueType& operator[](const KeyType& key) const {
            for (List<Pair, CompareFunction>::myIterator it = this->_pairs.begin();
            it != this->_pairs.end(); ++it) {
```

In this use of iterator, the compiler shouts:

```
Error   C2662   List<mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::Pair,CompareFunction>::myIterator List<mtm::MtmMap<KeyType,int,CompareFunction>::Pair,CompareFunction>::begin(void):  cannot convert 'this' from "const List<mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::Pair,CompareFunction>" to "List<mtm::MtmMap<int,int,std::less<KeyType>>::Pair,CompareFunction> &"
```

As I understand there is here a problem with const-correctness. I can't make the iterator const, then I wouldn't be able to iterate with it. How do I handle it ?

Comment: Note: You should implement the iterator in terms of a pointer - do not test the validity (just let the program crash)  and do not compare the content (just compare the pointer addresses). Also advance the pointer, if ask for, and let the program cash (if that advance is invalid).

Comment: I feel like some details are missing here. What do you even mean by `*at`? I don't see that anywhere in your code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe a typo for `*it`?

Comment: I choose exactly the piece of code which is relevant, the answer of ead is excellent.

Comment: For the second question: your begin() and end() are not const correct, thus you cannot call them in a const member function. You should declare them const like: `myIterator begin() const { return myIterator(head); }` (might be not so easy) or define a second const version of begin() and end() or discard const qualifier of  `operator[]` (easy but bad option)

Comment: Do you mean I need 2 versions of them, in additional to non-const, a const version, like with the operator []? 
Seems to be working, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some details missing, but

```
int operator*() { if (ptr_ ) return ptr_->Data(); else return 0; }
```

only works if ptr_->Data() is an int, which is probable not your intention. Shouldn't the return value be of DataType?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly is the problem. Now I just need to think how to return ptrnull, because it isn't DataType eather an the compiler complains about it. But great, thanks. Or maybe it can be usable to use here throw.

Comment: Hm... strange, how can I return the DataType object or nullptr if the signature is DataType? Any suggestions ?

Comment: if ptr is null you should raise an exception or return a default value

Comment: I've added an additional little trouble' hope you still here to give me some advice about it, thanks.